# Is it safe/energy efficient to surround hydronic baseboard heaters with a wooden enclosure?

Tags: heating, trim

I recently replaced some wood panelling with drywall, leaving my hydronic baseboard heaters free standing with no brackets or metal surrounding them. I was thinking that instead of putting a metal cover over them, I could build a slotted wooden enclosure that I would paint white to blend in with the baseboard trim.

Would I lose any energy efficiency by doing this? Is there a reason they are always made of metal?

Comment: Metal is a conductor, and transfers the heat from the heater to the room well. Wood would not transfer the heat as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metal is used because it is a LOT cheaper than a wood cover.

You can use wood covers, but you have to leave the top open to allow heat to escape (or have a grill). Also, you probably should make the opening at the top somewhat wider than with a metal cover. I would probably put a strip of metal on the inside of the baseboard to protect the wood from heat. The design is kind of like this:

[image: hydronic heater with wood cover]

If I did this I would also drill a lot of holes in the bottom of the outboard part of the heating frame or leave a good-size vent at the bottom somehow. You want to maximize the airflow. Cold air entering bottom, gets heated, exits through top grille.

Comment: I'll probably just leave the bottom open for maximum air flow.